# Torch and easyocr with python on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, torch, easyocr

I am trying to install and operate easyocr on a raspberry pi 3 model b.
For that i also needed torch.
I have installed both easyocr and pytorch, they installed succesfully.
But when i try to import them in python an error comes back "illegal instruction" and when i do it in the idle "RESTART: Shell" pops up.

My version of python is 3.9.2 64 bit.
numpy 1.24.2
torch 2.0.0
easyocr 1.6.2

I have tried downgrading numpy to 1.19.4

Some have tried to use anaconda, to download python or pytorch instead.
And if that might help i would need help installing anaconda on raspberry pi, cause i have been unsuccesful in that area as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got torch back to 1.13 and this problem was solved:

```
pip install torch==1.13.0 torchvision==0.14.0 torchaudio==0.13.0
```